# Keeping Score and Declaring a Winner Assistance in Word Game

Tags: c++

I've gotten most of this down, but there's only two things that are still getting me and a little push in the right direction can be oh so helpful. I'm supposed to be creating a word game with players and rounds and then at the end it should total up the scores and declare a winner. I've been able to get everything working except for tallying up the scores and declaring a winner. I've been able to have them show how many points a person earns each round, but I can't seem to have the totals carry over to each round. I've tried various things but I can't seem to get it. Any help going in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I also tried to add:

```
total_points[player_counter][round_counter] = input_word.length();
```

to my code, but it gave me an "expression must have a pointer-to-object type" for only player_counter, so I don't know where to add something in to make that go away.

Full Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int round_number;
int scores;
int players;
int player_scores;
string input_word;
int player_counter = 0;
int total_points = 0;
int winner = 0;
int win;

int main()
{
cout << "Welcome to the Word Game!" << endl << endl;

cout << "How many players will be participating?" << endl;
cin >> players;

cout << "\nHow many rounds will be played?" << endl;
cin >> round_number;
cin.ignore();

srand(time(0));

for (int round_counter = 1; round_counter <= round_number; round_counter++)
{
    cout << "\nRound: " << round_counter << endl;

    for (int player_counter = 1; player_counter <= players; player_counter++)
    {
        char beginning_letter = (rand() % 26) + 'a';

        cout << "\nPlayer " << player_counter << ": Please enter a word that begins with: " << beginning_letter << endl;
        getline(cin, input_word);

        cout << "Player " << player_counter << " has earned: " << input_word.length() << " points." << endl;

        total_points = input_word.length();
        cout << "\nPlayer " << player_counter << " Points: " << total_points << endl;
    }

}

cout << "\nThese are the end results!";

int sum = 0;
for (int end_score = 0; end_score < total_points; ++end_score)
{
    sum += total_points;
    end_score = total_points;

    for (int player_counter = 1; player_counter <= players; player_counter++)
    {
        cout << "\nPlayer " << player_counter << " Points: " << end_score << endl;
    }
}

cout << "Player " << player_counter << " is the winner!" << endl;

system("PAUSE");
```

Comment: `total_points[player_counter][round_counter] = input_word.length();` is.. sorry.. nonsense as `total_points` is an `int` not a 2d array. `total_points = input_word.length();` is almost right, but if you want to accumulate the totals (instead of overwriting the value in each round) you need something like `total_points += input_word.length();`. However, if you want to save the totals for several players you need some array/vector to store total for each player individually. Take a look at [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you necessarily (it may be mandatory for your task) have to calculate the total scores in a different loop, you don't really need a 2D array to store the scores of each round. In fact, you can store only the total scores of each player, updating them at every round:

```
#include <vector>

// ...

// store the scores in a vector of size players, initialized to 0
std::vector<int> scores(players); 

for ( int round = 1; round <= round_number; ++round )
{
    cout << "\nRound: " << round << endl;

    for ( int player = 0; player < players; ++player )
    //    the indeces ^^^ of arrays and vectors start from 0
    {
        // ... your stuff, like reading input_word...

        scores[player] += input_word.length();

        // here you print out the total score of the player so far
        cout << "\nPlayer " << ( player + 1 ) << " Points: " << scores[player] << endl;
    }
}
```

Next task is to find out who wins the game. It seems to me that this game can have more then a winner, as a matter of fact, different players may have earned the same total points. In this case a simple loop to find the index of the player with the maximum score will return only the first one (or the last, it depends on implementation), so I'll find out the max points and then print out all the players with that score in another loop:

```
int max_score = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < players; ++i )
{
    // Note that you already have printed the final scores in previous loop...
    cout << "Player " << ( i + 1 ) << " Points: " << scores[i] << '\n';

    // find max score
    if ( scores[i] > max_score )
        max_score = scores[i];
}

cout << "\nThe winner is...\n";
for (int i = 0; i < players; ++i )
{
    if ( scores[i] == max_score )
        cout << "Player " << ( i + 1 ) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I was trying your theory out, but for the vector, I keep getting a "vector subscript out of range line 1232" error. Don't know what's causing it. It only launches right after all the players have entered in their items and when trying to move to the next round.

[ http://scr.hu/7ex/0rmhs ]  Picture of the code since comments are too small to put in the entire thing in.

Comment: @VeVeXeDe in your code the indeces `player_counter` in the for loops start from `1` and go to `players` (included), so the last is out of bounds. In mine I start from `0` (it's higlighted in a comment) and never reach `players`. I didn't do that for `round` only because it isn't an array index.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that when it comes to players, entering 0 counts a player as player 0 for some reason, which is why I've kept it at 1.

Comment: @VeVeXeDe that's the reason why I use `( player + 1 )` and `( i + 1 )` when it comes to print the number that identifies the Player. Array indeces start from 0, so the score of the **first** player is stored in `scores[0]`, but when you have to print the number you have to use `cout << "Player " << ( 0 + 1 )`. That's the difference between the code I posted and yours (as I can see from the image you linked).

Comment: Okay, so I was able to have it start to work after I did just an array (I gave up because the vector was giving so  many issues. But, now I have it to where all that shows up is these big negative numbers [ http://scr.hu/7ex/7j6fr ] No idea where to go from here,but it's progress

Comment: @VeVeXeDe I'm afraid that you haven't understood my answer and my comments. The last snippet of code you linked seems to be randomly copy pasted. Please, take a deep look at [this](https://ideone.com/y4d77L) and try to figure out what's wrong in your code.

Comment: Hey, I just want to say thank you. This does make sense and I was able to work around with this and  make it all okay. I was working on this for an  hour or so straight last night and after a while, the frustration just built and I guess I just kind of got lost and couldn't really focus in. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

**Notice:** When I was finally done 2 post already was up with "arrays" still not taking up my point of "match round with player" so I'll post anyway

For me it feel that the structure of the program is wrong, what I see:

Game:

- X players
- X rounds
- track scores for players

My first assumtion would be, shouldn't the players therefore be decided before rounds? in your loop you do it the other way around?

Problems I see:

- How can you say that person X that played in round Y equals the person Z that played round Y+1?
- Everything in "single-point" variables, even when you have a unknown amount of players. Then I would say with high confidence it is impossible to do what you want with "single-point" variables

Solution:

Use arrays for storage! (where needed ofc)

Program structure (Something like this)

```
Init player count
for player count
-Init player
Init round count
for round
-save round score to player
display highest score
```

Comment: It's possible that I did switch them backwards when I began the loop, but since it gave me a correct output (where the amount of players would input and then once they're all done the next round would start) I didn't really notice because it still gave me what I was looking for. 

I didn't realize how much of my coding I guess had issues or problems; as coding is really not my strong suit. It's something I have trouble with but these are some good tips and I'll try to focus on putting in arrays for certain aspects. Thank you for the help~

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have only pasted something that won't compile.  Usually at Stack Overflow, we want compilable examples, but I understand what you are trying to do...

Are you familiar with arrays yet?  Right now, with only 1 score variable in memory, all players scores go to the same location.  With an array of scores, it would be easy to track per player and then perhaps they would not get stomped.  As is right now, `total_points` will track all player's scores instead of just the current player.  When you do use arrays, all you for loops starting at 1 and ending at `<=` the final value will cause you problems.  You will probably want to switch to starting at 0 and ending at `<` the final value.

That last for loop

`for(int end_score = 0; end_score < total_points; ++end_score)`

also is not doing at all what you want.  It will iterate once per total score value and your `sum` is going to be way off.  Instead, if you were to track the score per player in the game loop (in arrays), you won't need the outside total score loop at all, just the inner player loop.

I don't want to code this for you as this is a learning project for you, but I will say you are not too far off right now.  Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, I'm surprised it didn't compile  for you, since it's working for me, but this is before I added in that edit line. I took that out and it still complies fine minus you know tallying the scores. We have learned arrays, but I sometimes still get a bit lost when it comes to working on it, so I figured it had to be something along with that. 

Thank you for telling me the bottom one isn't working out, I had no idea and now I can also focus on fixing that and this is really helpful and I'm glad to hear I'm not at least too far off.

Thank you for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I used all suggestion above, so you can compare your code with mine.

```
int main()
{
    /*
    1. Init player count
    2. For player count
        init player
    3. Init round count
    4. For round
        save round score to player
    5. Display highest score
    */

    cout << "Welcome to the Word Game!" << endl << endl;

    // 1. Init player count
    cout << "How many players will be participating?> " << flush;
    int player_count;
    cin >> player_count;

    // 2. For player count, init player;
    vector<int> players;
    for (int i = 0; i < player_count; ++i) {

        players.push_back(i + 1);
    }

    cout << "\nHello!" << endl;
    for (vector<int>::const_iterator iter = players.begin(); iter != players.end(); ++iter) {
        cout << "Player: " << *iter << endl;
    }

    // 3. Init round count
    cout << "\nHow many rounds will be played?> " << flush;
    int round_number;
    cin >> round_number;

    // 4. For round, save round score to player
    srand(time(NULL));
    string input_word;
    vector<int> scores(player_count);       // initialize 'player_count' intergers in the vector with their default value = 0

    for (int i = 0; i < round_number; ++i) {
        cout << "\nRound: " << i + 1 << endl;
        char beginning_letter = 'a' + (rand() % 26);

        for (int j = 0; j < players.size(); ++j) {

            cout << "\nPlayer " << players[j] << ": Please enter a word that begins with: " << beginning_letter << " > " << flush;
            cin >> input_word;
            cout << "\nPlayer " << players[j] << " has earned: " << input_word.length() << " points in this round." << endl;
            scores[j] += input_word.length();
            cout << "Total: " << scores[j] << endl;
        }
    }
    // 5. Display highest score
    cout << "\nThese are the end results!";

    int high = 0;
    int play = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < scores.size(); ++k)
    {
        if (scores[k] > high) {
            high = scores[k];
            play = k;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nPlayer " << players[play] << " is the winner!" << " Score is: " << high << endl;


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```